# Reference folder in node_modules from index.html (create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, uikit

I have a project to try out React, so I used the create-react-app CLI to get the boilerplate.

I installed UIKit with npm so it's there in my node_modules folder, but I can't seem to reference it correctly from `index.html` in my public folder. node_modules is in the root directory, as is public, and since `index.html` is in the public folder I go up to the parent directory, and then into node_modules like so:

```
<script src="../node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
```

But... The reference to uikit icons isn't found. The pathing after node_modules is correct so that's not the problem. How should I solve this?

Comment: I hope you start your proj using `yarn start`, in that case just provide the path like this `<script src="node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>`

Comment: With react you have to think a bit differently, you shouldn’t just include scripts like you would with vanilla JS or jQuery, instead you should use components provided by packages, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/uikit-react, in your JSX or TSX files. CRA (technically webpack) handles packaging the third party library and making sure it is available when you publish. Unfortunately, uikit-react does not appear to be supported, but may still meet your needs. When searching for third-party UI libraries in react, make sure to find libraries that are specifically designed to work with react.

Answer (score 1):

The way CRA is pretty different. `create-react-app` uses [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) under the hood, it is a tool which will take your code and bundle it into a couple files and it will auto insert them into `public/index.html` and then put that into the `dist` folder. Since you want to use UIKit you would import the JS like this:

```js
import "uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js";
```

The reason you aren't importing something from it is because that file is meant to be loaded as a `<script>` and just `import`ing it makes it act like that. According to the UIKit documentation, [the way it acts is compatible with frameworks like React](https://getuikit.com/docs/javascript#uikit-and-reactive-javascript-frameworks) so it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that might be useful in some cases is to setup a `postinstall` npm script. Here you can run a script that copies your js file from your `node_modules` folder to the `public` folder, and from then on accessing it would be a piece of cake.

Example of npm script:

```json
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "node ./copy-dep.js",
  ...
}
```

Sample of copy script in Node:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.copyFile(
  path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/path/to/file.js'),
  path.join(__dirname, 'public/scripts/file.js'),
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('node_modules/path/to/file.js was copied to public/scripts/file.js');
  }
);
```

HTML script tag:

```html
<script src="./scripts/file.js"></script>
```